# How to add multiple models to collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, models

How to add multiple models to collection in Backbone

```
    formatChannelIds: function() {

    _this = this;

    // var activeIds ='';


    _.filter(_this.modelChannelList.toJSON(), function(channelObj) {
      if (channelObj['isactive'] == true) {
        //   activeIds =activeIds+','+channelObj['id'];
        console.log(channelObj['id']);
        _this.modelChannelStats.fetch({
          data: {
            channel: channelObj['id']
          },
          processData: true
        }, {
          success: function(model, response, options) {



            _this.channelstatsCollection.push(model);



          }

        });

      }

    });

    console.log(_this.channelstatsCollection);
    console.log(_this.modelChannelStats);


  }
```

My collection shows a null in the Array.

Answer (score -1):

Fetch method accepts one object containing all necessary params.

```
_this.modelChannelStats.fetch({
         data: {
           channel: channelObj['id']
         },
         processData: true,
         success: function(model, response, options) {
           _this.channelstatsCollection.push(model);

        }

    });
```

Try to use this piece of code.

Comment: You are passing two passing two objects inside fetch call.
{
          data: {
            channel: channelObj['id']
          },
          processData: true
  }

 {
          success: function(model, response, options) {
            _this.channelstatsCollection.push(model);
          }
}

All things should be wrapped inside one object for fetch.

Comment: i get a model in collection but not all the models only the last one

Comment: try to log your collection inside success callback, like success: function(model, response, options) {
           _this.channelstatsCollection.push(model);
            console.log(_this.channelstatsCollection);
}

inside each log you'll get one model added to your collection.